# iText error when adding Link onto Canvas

Tags: itext, itext7

I've run into a pretty strange problem in iText 7 that I'm hoping other people have dealt with in the past. I'm essentially just trying to create a table of contents by adding a series of Link objects into a Paragraph object, then dropping the Paragraph into a Canvas object. Here's a sample of simplified code:

```
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(document.getPdfDocument().addNewPage());
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(36, 650, 100, 100);
    pdfCanvas.rectangle(rectangle);
    pdfCanvas.stroke();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, document.getPdfDocument(), rectangle);
    canvas.add(new Paragraph(new Link("Google", PdfAction.createGoToR("HELLO", "www.google.com"))));
```

As you can see, this is pretty bare bones. When I do this, however, I am getting a null pointer exception. I can add simple text without having any problems, but the moment I add a link, things go haywire. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Why the down-vote? This is a legitimate question! I think I know the answer, but I need to test it first. (In the meantime, I "undid" the down-vote with an up-vote.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you could draw a rectangle (or in this case, a square) on a `PdfCanvas`:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage();
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(36, 650, 100, 100);
pdfCanvas.rectangle(rectangle);
pdfCanvas.stroke();
pdf.close();
```

You don't need a `Document` object. You just create a `PdfCanvas` and you draw a rectangular shape with as bottom-left corner `x = 36; y = 360` measuring 100 by 100 user units.

You introduce a `Document` object, because you also want to create a `Link`. That isn't necessary either. You could try this (but that would be wrong):

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, rectangle);
canvas.add(new Paragraph().add("Google"));
canvas.add(new Paragraph(new Link("Google", PdfAction.createGoToR("HELLO", "www.google.com"))));
pdf.close();
```

As you can see, we work with `pdf` (a `PdfDocument`) and `pdf` alone. There's no `Document` involved. However, you are trying to add a link to a `Canvas` object. A `Canvas` can be used if you want to add PDF syntax to the *content stream*. A link isn't part of the content stream. A link is an annotation that is stored in the `/Annots` entry of the page dictionary. In short: you are using `Canvas` for something it can't be used.

I think you are trying to put a link at an absolute position and that you want to put a rectangle around that link. That's not done using `Canvas`. It's much easier if you just put a `Paragraph` at an absolute position.

For instance:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
        .add(new Link("Google", PdfAction.createGoToR("HELLO", "www.google.com")))
        .setFixedPosition(36, 650, 80)
        .setBorder(new SolidBorder(0.5f));
    document.add(p);
    document.close();
}
```

This add a `Paragraph` at position `(x = 36; y = 650)` and a width of 80 user units. We add a 0.5 thick border around the `Paragraph`.

This won't work either, because the link is all wrong. You are using a `GoToR` (go to remote) action that is meant to go to a specific destination *in another PDF file*. I think that you want an URI action instead:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
        .add(new Link("Google", PdfAction.createURI("www.google.com")))
        .setFixedPosition(36, 650, 80)
        .setBorder(new SolidBorder(0.5f));
    document.add(p);
    document.close();
}
```

If you want to get more space around the text, you can change the padding:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
        .add(new Link("Google", PdfAction.createURI("www.google.com")))
        .setFixedPosition(36, 650, 80)
        .setPadding(10)
        .setBorder(new SolidBorder(0.5f));
    document.add(p);
    document.close();
}
```

This is much more intuitive than what you tried to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic reply! You not only helped me with my problem, but I understand a lot of the underlying concepts better now!